# How can I specify conditions to the "try" and "except" functions?

Tags: python

I have a list that could look like the following;

```
timeLength = ["1h", " 2h 1min", " 1h 37min", "1h 33min",''''']
```

What I want to do is convert all of these to integer minutes.
I have managed to make a try and except case that works for "2h 1min" and if h doesn't appear giving you an error then only use the min like so.

```
            try:
                hour, minute = timeLength.split("h")
                hour = (int(hour)* 60)
                minString = minute.strip("min")
                minString = re.findall(r'\d+', minString)
                minString = list(map(int, minString))
                minString = minString[0]
                totalLength = minString + hour
            except:
                hour = 0
                minString = timeLength.strip("min")
                minString = re.findall(r'\d+', minString)
                minString = list(map(int, minString))
                minString = minString[0]
                totalLength = hour + minString
print(totalLength)
```

What do I need to add to this to take into account instances that only have "h".

Note: There may be more instances that I haven't found yet so I need a way to easily add them in when they arise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe check `if "h" in timeLength:` and then split it.

Comment: Note that try and except *are not* functions. They work on regular blocks for which the same rules apply like everywhere else. You may want to clarify what you want to do *disregarding* any potential approach, be it exception handling, conditional branching, polymorphism or plain old regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally would tackle this with a single regex instead of trying to separately enumerate all possible formats:

```
import re

def to_minutes(s):
   h, m = re.match(r'(?:(\d+)h)?\s*(?:(\d+)min)?', s.strip()).groups()
   return int(h or 0) * 60 + int(m or 0)

timeLength = ["1h", " 2h 1min", " 1h 37min", "1h 33min"]
for s in timeLength:
  print(s, to_minutes(s))
```

Here:

- `(?:(\d+)h)?` optionally matches a number followed by `h`;
- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces;
- `(?:(\d+)min)?` optionally matches a number followed by `min`.

The `(\d+)` capture the numbers, and the surrounding `(?:)?` is simply a way to make something optional without also creating a capture group.

Finally, `h or 0` and `m or 0` simply replace `None` (which arise if the hours or minutes are not present in the input) with zeros to simplify calculations.

It is very easy to extend this scheme to more time units (days, weeks etc).

Note that if I were doing this in production code, I'd format the regex as [`re.VERBOSE` with inline comments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X).

Comment: Oof... I'm too slow... :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Have an upvote anyway. I think your answer deserves that.

Comment: Thanks, great help. Question though: What if I have a format that is say "1h30min" without the spaces or 1hour 30 minutes" or "1hour 30 min" etc How would I add those in.

Answer (score 2):

As long as we're using regex, might as well get full use out of it:

```
def to_minutes(text):
    match = re.match('\s*(\d+)h(?:\s*(\d+)m)?', timelength)
    if match is None:
         # it wasn't a valid string, so handle the error as you like
    else:
         h, m = match.groups()
         # the `m` may be None, but otherwise both values are valid for `int`.
         if m is None:
             m = 0
         return int(h) * 60 + int(m)
```

Breaking down the regex:

```
\s*(\d+)h(?:\s*(\d+)m)?
^^^
zero or more whitespace chars
   ^^^^^^
   digits followed by 'h' (captured)
         ^^^         ^^
         optionally this stuff, but don't make a capturing group
            ^^^
            whitespace again
               ^^^^^^
               digits followed by 'm' (captured)
```

Each successful match, then, has groups for the hour and minute counts. When the minute count group (made optional by the `(?:...)?` that it's wrapped in) isn't matched, that group captures `None` instead of a substring. The non-capturing group lets us specify what's being made optional with the final `?`, but without making another group that captures the `m` and leading whitespace.